# Rasp PI spectrum analyzer led strip length

Tags: led

I'm new to raspberry-pi and electronics. I was looking to this tutorial:
https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-spectrum-analyzer-display-on-rgb-led-strip/page-1

Is it possible to build that spectrum analyzer but with longer rgb led strip??
For example 5m rgb led strip? Can PI handle that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Raspberry Pi can handle a lot of LEDs.

Building 5m strip (with that many separate "channels") is more challenging.